# HTML 5 video gets paused randomly on Chrome

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, html5-video

The problem is what I said on the Title, I have a video element, and randonmly it gets paused only in chrome. **Note that I am working on top of Angular 4 and this 'bug' only happens on chrome**.

More explained, the video is paused when some outer component changes its model or some other change and the inner video component gets paused, but not always... I just don't know why this happens. **Is there a way to set a video never pausable?**

This is my HTML code on top of Angular:

```
<video #video autoplay></video>
```

I came with this workaround for the moment, but this is not what I expect as I final solution:

```
videoElem.onpause = () => {
    videoElem.play();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In angular, try adding `[muted]="true"` attribute to video tag